# Hibernate session in Seam conversation grows too large

Tags: hibernate, seam

We are using a Seam conversation for a wizard that spans multiple pages, some of these screens load a lot of data for user selection (can be several thousand records). The Hibernate session is holding onto everything, which is an issue for both memory usage and performance (as flush takes several seconds).

Is our only option evicting data as we load it or is there a better way to manage this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have screens that keep several thousand records in the session (depending, obviously, on how big those records are) for an extended period of time, sure, you're going to have problems.

How to solve the problem depends on a lot of factors.

- Is it app-wide data that can be stored in a single place?
- Can you cache it either at the Hibernate level (like with ehcache), or in...
- ...an external cache that sits between the app and the DB?
- Do you need to keep *all* the data in those records, or would a small subset (like an id and label) suffice?

Etc.

Comment: The data is cached at the Hibernate level using ehcache, but it still ends up in the Hibernate session when it is loaded. We do need all that data. Currently we are trying out using a second Hibernate session that exists only around the service call, not sure that it's the best option though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to save **everything** in a conversation.

Just keep the data inserted by the user and use a Event scope for the queries, and make a query each time you access the page of the wizard.

Just don't keep the results of the query.

Comment: The results of the query are not being put into the conversation, the Hibernate session is keeping the results and Seam keeps the Hibernate session in conversation.